# Friction points on a Roberval balance scale

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image][image]
I need to make a simple yet sensitive balance scale with a **single** pivot point, as shown. I can also make a Roberval balance scale which requires **6** pivot points, as shown. But wouldn't having 6 pivot points increase the friction experienced by the scale, thereby lowering its sensitivity? I know a Roberval scale automatically levels its pans, but if it has less sensitivity, I wonder if it's worth it?